# Bad sectors on brand new NVMe SSD's

Tags: partitioning, ssd, disk-image, bad-sectors, dell-optiplex

At work I have roughly 50 brand new Dell Optiplex 7070's with LiteOn SSD's that were loaded with a custom Windows 10 image using Acronis Cyber Backup 12.5.

A few weeks after imaging, ~30 of these PC's started giving constant bad sector errors in event viewer and when running a surface test with [Macrorit Disk Scanner](https://macrorit.com/disk-surface-test/disk-surface-test.html), all at different times.

Eventually 4 of them crashed with constant blue screens around the same time of one another.

Reimaging the drives outright didn't seem to clear any of the bad blocks on the surface test.

Installing a clean version of Windows 10 and imaging over that seemed to clear any bad sectors when I ran the surface test again, but then bad sector errors started popping up days later with one of the PC's crashing again.

Does anyone have any insight if this possibly a hardware issue with a bad batch of SSD's from Dell? Or could there be some kind of problem with the way that the PC's are being imaged/the image itself? If it is a hardware issue, wouldn't the surface test constantly find bad sectors even after a clean windows installation?

Comment: Sounds like something covered by your warranty

Comment: It most likely is, but after getting nowhere with Dell support I was hoping to avoid having to replace 50 drives.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with Dell devices, acquired directly from Dell, that had varying firm wares and device drivers, but otherwise each workstation looked the same as the next.  Suggested courses: [1] verify that motherboard and NVMe work together and drivers for both are current;  [2] check the BIOS boot settings for UEFI; [3] can the image from Acronis be burned to a USB instead, then installed from the windows setup process to the NVMe?  This dell solution might address your issue: https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Precision-7710-unable-to-load-windows-10-on-NVME-M-2/td-p/7301285

Comment: The drivers are up to date for both, and the PC's came directly from Dell with the NVMe drives installed. I might have to try burning the image to a USB like you suggested. Also, UEFI is enabled, but one thing I'm not sure about based on that link you provided is whether or not the fact that I have them booting in RAID On instead of AHCI is causing issues. After imaging with Acronis, if I reboot with AHCI instead of RAID , it fails to find the boot device, so I've been using RAID On instead.

Comment: Was the original OS from a former PC's NVMe or is this a cross media restore? looks like AHCI is preferred... another link of potential interest for you: https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Pros-Cons-AHCI-vs-Raid-On-XPS13-9300-NVMe/td-p/7636984

Comment: The image was built from one of the same model PCs with the same model NVMe drive in it. I might try switching the PC's to AHCI and seeing what happens.